# Any workaround for the LWR3008 error (404 status) while accessing a LWC screen flow component in an LWR site?

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow, digital-experience, flow-screen-component, lightning-web-runtime

Support for flows in an LWR site that can contain LWCs was [announced in Summer '22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_flow_component.htm&release=238&type=5). But right now, I can't get that to work, and see a 404 status on the GET of the first LWC embedded in the flow:

```
https://abc-def-9876-dev-ed.scratch.my.site.com
/MYSITE/webruntime/component/latest/dev/en-US/myNs%2FmyComponent
```

with this message reported:

> Something went wrong with the "MyComponent" screen component on the "My Flow" flow. Contact your Salesforce admin about this error. LWR3008: Error loading https://abc-def-9876-dev-ed.scratch.my.site.com/MYSITE/webruntime/component/latest/dev/en-US/myNs%2FmyComponent

The site:

- was setup using `sf community create --name MYSITE --template-name 'Build Your Own (LWR)' --url-path-prefix MYSITE templateParams.AuthenticationType=AUTHENTICATED_WITH_PUBLIC_ACCESS_ENABLED`
- appears to be an [Enhanced LWR Site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_enhanced_lwr.htm&release=240&type=5)
- has non-flow LWCs working correctly
- is using 100% LWC components already working in an older Aura template site

The same problem has been reported in these places with no accepted answer posted:

- 11 months ago ["LWR3008: Error" from LWC component in Flow on a digital experiences page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396762/lwr3008-error-from-lwc-component-in-flow-on-a-digital-experiences-page)
- 6 months ago [Receiving "LWR3008" error while accessing a LWC screen flow component in LWR sites](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T6JTrSAN)
- 3 months ago [Receiving "LWR3008" error while accessing a LWC screen flow component in LWR sites](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409699/receiving-lwr3008-error-while-accessing-a-lwc-screen-flow-component-in-lwr-sit)

Two questions:

- **Q1**: Is there a work-around for this problem?
- **Q2**: Does this work at all for you e.g. with no namespaces and no packaging involved?

(I opened a case #46129847 with Salesforce but that did not get me very far.)

Comment: Is this a regular user or Guest Site User? I know with GSU I had to check the "allow guest users to access public APIs" in Preferences for flows to work, so wonder if it is something to do with that requirement?

Comment: Thanks @BritishBoyinDC; the error is happening for a registered and logged in user for the site. I looked around in the profile and the "process automation settings" but didn't find anything promising. Any other places to look? (The profile is the same one that works in an Aura site.)

Comment: I have been able to  get this to work, as a point of reference:
LWR Enhanced SIte
Screen Flow => Invocable => Screen with Embedded LWC using results from invocable
LWC is just iterating over a list of sObjects

Comment: This issue may be related to the API version. I would suggest upgrading all LWCs to v59.0. It is not directly related, but it may help.

"For screen flows that are configured to run on API versions 57.0 and 58.0, on the Process Automation Settings page, select Enable Reactive Components for Screen Flows running API Version 57.0 and 58.0. Add components to your screen, and save and run your flows as usual."

Source:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform-app-builder-certification-maintenance-winter-24/maintain-your-platform-app-builder-certification-for-winter-24

Comment: Thanks @PabloFischer. Going for 59.0 removes another variable (think this [Build Screen Flows with Reactive Components (Generally Available)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_build_screen_flows_with_reactive_components_generally_available.htm&release=246&type=5) may be a better link) but making only that change - on the LWCs and the flow - did not fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the cause of my problem is that instead of directly using the `flow` component I have an LWC (`wrapped-flow`) wrapping the `lightning-flow` to improve the startup behaviour e.g. spinner over a card.

If both of these are in the experience page both work. If only `flow` is in the page it works. If only `wrapped-flow` is in the page I get the LWR-3008 error. Pretty weird.

On the general areas of "no Aura", this [Flows Work with Experience LWR Sites (and why “Navigate Everywhere” and “Open URL” Don’t Work There Yet)](https://unofficialsf.com/flows-work-with-experience-lwr-sites-and-why-navigate-everywhere-and-open-url-dont-work-there-yet/) explains that some LWC components still layer on top of Aura. So, for example, a LWC that I have that uses `lightning-file-upload` doesn't render anything for that `lightning-file-upload` or after that. So somewhat open ended "gotchas" possible.